# Iphone - debugging the GenericKeychain example

Tags: iphone, code-signing

I'm trying to run the GenericKeychain from Apple's website : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html

after a lot of struggles with "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.", it turns out i need an ad hoc provisioning profile to make their example work.
The main problem with this is that i can't debug my app when i sign it with a distribution profile.

Is there any way to debug with a distribution profile ? Or to run the GenericKeychain with a developer profile ?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the fresh GenericKeychain and tested it in Xcode 4: No problem. The only thing you have to do, is to set the "Base SDK" of the project & the two targets "GenericKeychain" and "GenericKeychain2" to "Latest iOS".

You need to do two things to get the app work on your device:

- Get the APP_ID of your app from the
  "Apple Developer - iOS Provisioning
  Portal - AppIDs". You may create a
  new APP_ID or use the "Xcode:
  Wildcard AppID" for testing &
  developing purpose.
- Replace the "YOUR_APP_ID_HERE" within
  sourcecode ... and don't forget to
  change it in the
  KeychainAccessGroups.plist &
  KeychainAccessGroups2.plist.

Now you should be able to test the demo app on the device.

Comment: I did all that, and it works on the simulator too, my problem is making it work on a iOS device, since on the simulator, there is no real keychain access group.

Comment: I just tested it on the device ... got the same error, you described, ... solved it and updated the answer :) Hope it also works for you!

Comment: I still can't make it work, if i sign my app with an iphone distribution profile, it will launch, but i won't be able to debug it with GDB and such. if i sign my app with an iphone developper profile, i get the error i described earlier.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with an app that previously worked on Xcode 3 with a device ... but now I get this error once I start using Xcode 4. The plot thickens ... !