# Storing keys in KeyChain with KeyChainItemWrapper

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keychain, xcode

I'm using KeyChainItemWrapper class, provided by Apple's Sample Code to save the authentication token to the keychain.

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier"JetTaxiApp_AuthToken" accessGroup:nil];
```

But when I'm trying to set the value to keychain, an odd exception is raised

```
[_authenticationTokenKeychain setObject:authenticationToken forKey: @"auth_token"];
```

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't add the Keychain
>   Item.'

The keychain doesn't exist yet (at the moment of this call)
What can cause this exception?

Comment: Make sure you added the keychain access plist file.
Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859615/iphone-debugging-the-generickeychain-example

Answer (score 33):

You need to use standard keys, so here your `@"auth_token"` is incorrect.

> The keys that can be used for this purpose and the possible values for each key are listed in the “Keychain Services Constants” section.

source, with list of valid constants: [Keychain Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html)

For instance, you can use:

> [_authenticationTokenKeychain setObject:authenticationToken forKey: (__bridge NSString *)kSecValueData];

Comment: When using the ARC version of keychainItemWrapper, you need to do it the following way : `[_authenticationTokenKeychain setValue:authenticationToken forKey:(__bridge NSString*)kSecValueData];`

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU I'm using the ARC version but I'm still having issues. I get this error: '[<KeychainItemWrapper 0x89c5900> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key v_Data.' Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: @Interfector instead of using **setValue**, use **setObject**

Answer (score 0):

```
[_authenticationTokenKeychain setObject:authenticationToken forKey: @"auth_token"];
```

For code snippet above, key param is only can use the keys provided from sdk.
You can find all in SecItem.h