# Keychain for userdata on ios6

Tags: ios6

I have the following code for storing data in the keychain:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:MounzaKeyName accessGroup:nil];

[keychainItem setObject:txtPassword.text forKey:kSecValueRef];
[keychainItem setObject:txtLogin.text forKey:kSecValueData];
```

However, whenever I run it, i'm getting the following:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't update the Keychain Item.'
```

Is there anything I am missing? I tried to investigate this..its happening right after the user is logging in. I'm trying to store the username and password in the code...

Online it was saying that i should be using standard keys, which I am:

[Storing keys in KeyChain with KeyChainItemWrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117885/storing-keys-in-keychain-with-keychainitemwrapper)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one keychain wrapper per value. You are trying to put two values into one wrapper. Create two wrappers with two different identifiers. In both cases you set a value for the kSecValueData key.

Comment: Are you sure? that page had a user using it with username and password?

Comment: I looked at the SO link you posted. I don't see any such use. Though I may be mistaken. Try using the kSecAttrAccount key for the username and the kSecValueData key for the password with a single wrapper.